# Parallel 3D Discrete Cosine Transformation Implementation in Matlab

Tags: performance, algorithm, matrix, matlab

I am trying to implement 3D Discrete Cosine Transformation calculation in Matlab with parallel computing `parfor`. The formula of 3D Discrete Cosine Transformation is as follows.

[image]

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of 3D Discrete Cosine Transformation function is `DCT3D`.

```
function X=DCT3D(x)

[N1,N2,N3] = size(x);
X=zeros(N1,N2,N3);

for k1=0:N1-1
    for k2=0:N2-1
        for k3=0:N3-1
            sumResult=0;            
            parfor n1=0:N1-1
                for n2=0:N2-1
                    for n3=0:N3-1
                        sumResult=sumResult+...
                            x(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1)*...
                            cos(pi/(2*N1)*(2*n1+1)*k1)*...
                            cos(pi/(2*N2)*(2*n2+1)*k2)*...
                            cos(pi/(2*N3)*(2*n3+1)*k3);
                    end
                end
            end
            X(k1+1,k2+1,k3+1)=8*sumResult*CalculateK(k1)*CalculateK(k2)*CalculateK(k3)/(N1*N2*N3);            
        end
    end
end
```

Moreover, the used function `CalculateK`:

```
function output = CalculateK(x)
  output = ones(size(x));
  output(x==0) = 1 / sqrt(2);
```

**Test cases**

```
%% Create test cells
testCellsSize = 10;

test = zeros(testCellsSize, testCellsSize, testCellsSize);
for x = 1:size(test, 1)
    for y = 1:size(test, 2)
        for z = 1:size(test, 3)
            test(x, y, z) = x * 100 + y * 10 + z;
        end
    end
end

%% Perform test
result = DCT3D(test);

%% Print output
for z = 1:size(result, 3)
    fprintf('3D DCT result: %d plane\n' , z);
    for x = 1:size(result, 1)
        for y = 1:size(result, 2)
            fprintf('%f\t' , result(x, y, z));
        end
        fprintf('\n');
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end

%% Visualize result

for z = 1:size(result, 3)
    figure;
    mesh(result(:, :, z));
end
```

The output of the test code above:

```
3D DCT result: 1 plane
1726.754760 -80.720722  -0.000000   -8.646042   -0.000000   -2.828427   0.000000    -1.143708   -0.000000   -0.320717   
-807.207224 0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-86.460422  -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-28.284271  -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-11.437076  -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-3.207174   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 2 plane
-8.072072   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    

3D DCT result: 3 plane
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 4 plane
-0.864604   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   

3D DCT result: 5 plane
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   

3D DCT result: 6 plane
-0.282843   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   

3D DCT result: 7 plane
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 8 plane
-0.114371   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 9 plane
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 10 plane
-0.032072   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Another test pattern:

```
%% Create test cells
testCellsSize = 10;

test = zeros(testCellsSize, testCellsSize, testCellsSize);
for z = 1:size(test, 3)
    test(:, :, z) = mod(z, 2) * 255;
end

%% Perform test
result = DCT3D(test);

%% Print output
for z = 1:size(result, 3)
    fprintf('3D DCT result: %d plane\n' , z);
    for x = 1:size(result, 1)
        for y = 1:size(result, 2)
            fprintf('%f\t' , result(x, y, z));
        end
        fprintf('\n');
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end

%% Visualize result

for z = 1:size(result, 3)
    fig = figure;
    mesh(result(:, :, z));
    saveas(fig, [num2str(z) '.bmp'], 'bmp');
end
```

The output of the test code above:

```
3D DCT result: 1 plane
360.624458  0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    

3D DCT result: 2 plane
51.635721   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    

3D DCT result: 3 plane
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 4 plane
57.238638   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    

3D DCT result: 5 plane
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   

3D DCT result: 6 plane
72.124892   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 7 plane
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    

3D DCT result: 8 plane
112.337152  0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 9 plane
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    

3D DCT result: 10 plane
326.015114  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
-0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    
0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   
0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   
-0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
```

The output figures:

[image: Plane1]

[image: Plane2]

[image: Plane3]

[image: Plane4]

[image: Plane5]

[image: Plane6]

[image: Plane7]

[image: Plane8]

[image: Plane9]

[image: Plane10]

**Test Platform Information**

Matlab version: '9.10.0.1629609 (R2021a)'

#### Sep. 9, 2021 Update

With referring [Cris Luengo's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/267720/231235), I realized that not only 3D IDCT, but also 3D DCT can be vectorized as the following code.

```
function out = DCT3D(x)
    [N1,N2,N3] = size(x);
    out = DCT1D(x, 1);
    out = DCT1D(out, 2);
    out = DCT1D(out, 3);
    out = 8 .* out ./ (N1 * N2 * N3);
end

function out = DCT1D(x, dim)
    N = size(x, dim);
    sz = ones(1,3);
    sz(dim) = N;
    index = {':',':',':'};
    out = zeros(size(x));
    for n = 0:N-1
       alpha = cos(pi/(2*N)*(2*(0:N-1)+1)*n);
       alpha = reshape(alpha, sz);
       index{dim} = n + 1;
       sum_result = sum(x .* alpha, dim);
       if n == 0
           sum_result = sum_result / sqrt(2);
       end
       out(index{:}) = sum_result;
    end
end
```

The implementation of this version have been tested with the test cases above.

**Reference**

- Malavika Bhaskaranand and Jerry D. Gibson, “Distributions of 3D DCT coefficients for video,” in Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, 2009.
- J. Augustin Jacob and N. Senthil Kumar, “Determining Optimal Cube for 3D-DCT Based Video Compression for Different Motion Levels,” ICTACT Journal on Image and Video Processing, Vol. 03, November 2012.
- Related [Code Golf coding challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/219203/100303).

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Comment: I don’t have time to write a full answer, but I’ll leave three short comments: (1) `parfor` is always best used as the outer loop. (2) Vectorize your code. (3) The DCT is separable.