# Three-dimensional DCT spatial frequency components illustration

Tags: algorithm, image, matrix, matlab, data-visualization

I am attempting to make three-dimensional discrete cosine transformation spatial frequency components illustration. The 3D cubes is used to present the level of each coefficient. The more bright the cube, the higher value of its coefficient, and vice versa. The 3D inverse discrete cosine transformation is used here and the formula is given as below.

The 3D inverse discrete cosine transformation $$x(n_1, n_{2}, n_{3})$$ of size $$N_{1} \times N_{2} \times N_{3}$$ is

$$x(n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}) = \sum_{{k_1 = 0}}^{N_1 - 1} \sum_{{k_2 = 0}}^{N_2 - 1} \sum_{{k_3 = 0}}^{N_3 - 1} \epsilon_{k_{1}} \epsilon_{k_{2}} \epsilon_{k_{3}} X(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3})
        \times \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{1}} (2n_{1} + 1)k_{1}})
        \times \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{2}} (2n_{2} + 1)k_{2}})
        \times \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{3}} (2n_{3} + 1)k_{3}})
$$

where

$$
n_{1} = 0, 1, \dots, N_{1} - 1
$$

$$
n_{2} = 0, 1, \dots, N_{2} - 1
$$

$$
n_{3} = 0, 1, \dots, N_{3} - 1
$$

$$
\epsilon_{k_{i}} = 
        \begin{cases}
            \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \text{for $k_{i} = 0$} \\
            1 & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
        i = 1, 2, 3
$$

**The experimental implementation**

- `plot3dcube` function implementation: The function `plotcube` is from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15161-plotcube).

  ```
  function [] = plot3dcube(input_array, alpha, title_text, xlabel_text, ylabel_text, zlabel_text)
      for z = 1:size(input_array, 3)
          for y = 1:size(input_array, 2)
              for x = 1:size(input_array, 1)
                  cubeColorR = input_array(x, y, z);
                  cubeColorG = input_array(x, y, z);
                  cubeColorB = input_array(x, y, z);
                  plotcube([1 1 1], [x - 1 y - 1 z - 1], alpha, [cubeColorR cubeColorG cubeColorB]);
              end
          end
      end
      title(title_text);
      xlabel(xlabel_text);
      ylabel(ylabel_text);
      zlabel(zlabel_text);
  end
  ```
- `IDCT3D.m`: The implementation of inverse DCT calculation.

  ```
  function IDCT3DOutput=IDCT3D(X)

  N1=size(X,1);
  N2=size(X,2);
  N3=size(X,3);

  for n1=0:N1-1
      for n2=0:N2-1
          for n3=0:N3-1
              sm=0;
              parfor k1=0:N1-1
                  for k2=0:N2-1
                      for k3=0:N3-1
                          if(k1==0)
                              alpha1 = 1/sqrt(2);
                          else
                              alpha1 = 1;
                          end
                          if(k2==0)
                              alpha2 = 1/sqrt(2);
                          else
                              alpha2 = 1;
                          end
                          if(k3==0)
                              alpha3 = 1/sqrt(2);
                          else
                              alpha3 = 1;
                          end
                          sm=sm+ alpha1*alpha2*alpha3*X(k1+1,k2+1,k3+1)*...  
                              cos(pi/(2*N1)*(2*n1+1)*k1)*cos(pi/(2*N2)*(2*n2+1)*k2)*cos(pi/(2*N3)*(2*n3+1)*k3);                        
                      end
                  end
              end
              IDCT3DOutput(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1)=sm;
          end
      end
  end
  ```

The main testing code:

```
sizex = 8;
sizey = 8;
sizez = 8;
OutputFigureLocation = "./Figures/";

OutputCollection = cell(sizex, sizey, sizez);

%%% calculation
for z = 1:sizez
    for y = 1:sizey
        for x = 1:sizex
            Input = zeros(sizex, sizey, sizez);
            Input(x, y, z) = 1;
            Output = IDCT3D(Input);
            Output = (Output + 1) ./ 2;         %%  Adjust the range of numbers
            OutputCollection{x, y, z} = {Output};
            fprintf('%d_%d_%d size 3D IDCT: The %d_%d_%d / %d_%d_%d block calculation has done. \n' , sizex, sizey, sizez, x, y, z, sizex, sizey, sizez);
        end
    end
end

%%% plot
alpha = 0.3;
title_text = "Three-dimensional DCT spatial frequency components";
xlabel_text = 'x';
ylabel_text = 'y';
zlabel_text = 'z';
for z = 1:sizez
    for y = 1:sizey
        for x = 1:sizex
            close all;
            OutputFilename = OutputFigureLocation + x + '_' + y + '_' + z + '.png';
            if isfile(OutputFilename)
                continue;
            end
            plot3dcube(OutputCollection{x, y, z}{1}, alpha, title_text, xlabel_text, ylabel_text, zlabel_text);
            saveas(gcf, OutputFilename);
        end
    end
end


function [] = plot3dcube(input_array, alpha, title_text, xlabel_text, ylabel_text, zlabel_text)
    for z = 1:size(input_array, 3)
        for y = 1:size(input_array, 2)
            for x = 1:size(input_array, 1)
                cubeColorR = input_array(x, y, z);
                cubeColorG = input_array(x, y, z);
                cubeColorB = input_array(x, y, z);
                plotcube([1 1 1], [x - 1 y - 1 z - 1], alpha, [cubeColorR cubeColorG cubeColorB]);
            end
        end
    end
    title(title_text);
    xlabel(xlabel_text);
    ylabel(ylabel_text);
    zlabel(zlabel_text);
end
```

The several output examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Another approach - with [`cellfun` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)**

Besides using nested `for` for IDCT calculation, there is another way to simplify with `cellfun` function:

```
sizex = 8;
sizey = 8;
sizez = 8;
OutputFigureLocation = "./Figures/";

%%%    construct input blocks
InputCollection = cell(sizex, sizey, sizez);
for z = 1:sizez
    for y = 1:sizey
        for x = 1:sizex
            Input = zeros(sizex, sizey, sizez);
            Input(x, y, z) = 1;
            InputCollection{x, y, z} = Input;
        end
    end
end

%%% calculation
OutputCollection = cell(sizex, sizey, sizez);
OutputCollection = cellfun(@IDCT3D, InputCollection, 'UniformOutput', false);
OutputCollection = cellfun(@myoffset, OutputCollection, 'UniformOutput', false);
save("OutputCollection_" + sizex + "_" + sizey + "_" + sizez + ".mat", "OutputCollection");

%%% plot
%load("OutputCollection_" + sizex + "_" + sizey + "_" + sizez + ".mat");
alpha = 0.3;
title_text = "Three-dimensional DCT spatial frequency components";
xlabel_text = 'x';
ylabel_text = 'y';
zlabel_text = 'z';
for z = 1:sizez
    for y = 1:sizey
        for x = 1:sizex
            close all;
            OutputFilename = OutputFigureLocation + x + '_' + y + '_' + z + '.png';
            if isfile(OutputFilename)
                continue;
            end
            plot3dcube(OutputCollection{x, y, z}, alpha, title_text, xlabel_text, ylabel_text, zlabel_text);
            saveas(gcf, OutputFilename);
        end
    end
end

function [output_array] = myoffset(input_array)
    output_array = (input_array + 1) ./ 2;         %%  Adjust the range of numbers
end

function [] = plot3dcube(input_array, alpha, title_text, xlabel_text, ylabel_text, zlabel_text)
    for z = 1:size(input_array, 3)
        for y = 1:size(input_array, 2)
            for x = 1:size(input_array, 1)
                cubeColorR = input_array(x, y, z);
                cubeColorG = input_array(x, y, z);
                cubeColorB = input_array(x, y, z);
                plotcube([1 1 1], [x - 1 y - 1 z - 1], alpha, [cubeColorR cubeColorG cubeColorB]);
            end
        end
    end
    title(title_text);
    xlabel(xlabel_text);
    ylabel(ylabel_text);
    zlabel(zlabel_text);
end
```

The syntax `OutputCollection = cellfun(@IDCT3D, InputCollection, 'UniformOutput', false)` used above is for calculating **each** cell in `InputCollection` with `IDCT3D` function and return the result to `OutputCollection`. However, as far as I know, there is one disadvantage which is that the intermediate status of calculation cannot be passed out. In other words, not like the `for` loop version which the saving operation can be inserted in to save the intermediate status, the object `OutputCollection` isn't updated until `cellfun` finish all the calculation. Based on this reason, I prefer to use the `for` version than the `cellfun` version. I am looking forward to some feedback, such as any other pros and cons, for the `for` loop version and the `cellfun` version.

**Reference**

- Wikipedia - [Discrete cosine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)
- Malavika Bhaskaranand and Jerry D. Gibson, “Distributions of 3D DCT coefficients for video,” in Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, 2009.
- J. Augustin Jacob and N. Senthil Kumar, “Determining Optimal Cube for 3D-DCT Based Video Compression for Different Motion Levels,” ICTACT Journal on Image and Video Processing, Vol. 03, November 2012.

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Comment: In the equation at the top of the post, you probably meant to sum over k, not x. You also have two copies of the `plot3dcube` function. I maybe have time tonight to write a review, I see lots of opportunities for improvement, writing a review will take time! :)

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thank you for letting me know the problem. The formula has been updated and it might be correct. If there is any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DCT computation can be made significantly more efficient, though for these small array sizes it doesn't matter a whole lot. I'll tackle this in the 2nd part of this answer. First I'll discuss some MATLAB syntax and style improvements.

> ```
> OutputCollection{x, y, z} = {Output};
> ```

This puts `Output` into a 1x1 cell array, and assigns this cell array into the larger cell array. You needed to retrieve your array later with `OutputCollection{x, y, z}{1}` because of this. The `{1}` is surprising, and useless. Instead, assign with either of these two syntaxes:

```
OutputCollection{x, y, z} = Output;
OutputCollection(x, y, z) = {Output};
```

Either one of them assigns the array directly into one of the cells of the cell array.

> ```
> function [] = plot3dcube(...)
> ```

It is not necessary to give `[]=` here:

```
function plot3dcube(...)
```

> ```
> cubeColorR = input_array(x, y, z);
> cubeColorG = input_array(x, y, z);
> cubeColorB = input_array(x, y, z);
> plotcube([1 1 1], [x - 1 y - 1 z - 1], alpha, [cubeColorR cubeColorG cubeColorB]);
> ```

Here you assigned the same value to three different variables. Simpler would be:

```
cubeColor = [1 1 1] * input_array(x, y, z);
plotcube([1 1 1], [x - 1 y - 1 z - 1], alpha, cubeColor);
```

The MATLAB Editor highlights this line:

> ```
> IDCT3DOutput(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1)=sm;
> ```

and notes that the variable changes size every loop iteration. This is highly inefficient. You should **always** [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). Simply adding a line

```
IDCT3DOutput = zeros(N1,N2,N3);
```

at the top of the function, before the loops, significantly speeds up execution.

Your loops are sorted in reverse order. When looping over an array, indexed with `X(k1,k2,k3)`, the loop over `k1` should be the inner loop, and the one over `k3` should be the outer loop. This causes the code to access the values in the array `X` in memory order, which is much faster because the cache will be used better. Likewise for the other three loops that iterate over the output array `IDCT3DOutput`. A 8x8x8 array is likely not large enough for this to matter a whole lot, but doing the same for a larger array that doesn't fit in the cache will make a big difference.

`parfor` should always be the outer loop. There is an overhead in distributing the work over the workers (and hopefully you have these configured as threaded, rather than separate processes as is the default), and doing so once or `N1 * N2 * N3` times makes a big difference.

> ```
> N1=size(X,1);
> N2=size(X,2);
> N3=size(X,3);
> ```

can be more easily written as

```
[N1,N2,N3] = size(X);
```

Finally, try to be consistent with spacing around operators. Some assignments you don't use any spacing around the operator, and some you have spaces on both sides. I'd suggest to pick one style, and use it consistently. It's worst when there's spaces on one side of an operator only:

> ```
> sm=sm+ alpha1 ...
> ```

is not as easy to read as

```
sm = sm + alpha1 ...
```

---

In this second part I want to discuss the implementation of the algorithm itself, which can be much more efficient. Let's look at the three inner loops only:

```matlab
sm=0;
parfor k1=0:N1-1
   for k2=0:N2-1
      for k3=0:N3-1
         if(k1==0)
            alpha1 = 1/sqrt(2);
         else
            alpha1 = 1;
         end
         if(k2==0)
            alpha2 = 1/sqrt(2);
         else
            alpha2 = 1;
         end
         if(k3==0)
            alpha3 = 1/sqrt(2);
         else
            alpha3 = 1;
         end
         sm=sm+ alpha1*alpha2*alpha3*X(k1+1,k2+1,k3+1)*...
            cos(pi/(2*N1)*(2*n1+1)*k1)*cos(pi/(2*N2)*(2*n2+1)*k2)*cos(pi/(2*N3)*(2*n3+1)*k3);
      end
   end
end
IDCT3DOutput(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1)=sm;
```

You are doing a terrible amount of useless work. For example, you test `if(k1==0)` `N2*N3` times too many. For the `k2` and `k3` loops, this is a constant, so move the computation out of those loops. The same is true for the `cos` computations, which are quite expensive. This could look like this (additionally I've reversed the loop order as discussed earlier):

```matlab
sm = 0;
for k3=0:N3-1
   if(k3==0)
      alpha3 = 1/sqrt(2);
   else
      alpha3 = 1;
   end
   alpha3 = alpha3 * cos(pi/(2*N3)*(2*n3+1)*k3);
   for k2=0:N2-1
      if(k2==0)
         alpha2 = 1/sqrt(2);
      else
         alpha2 = 1;
      end
      alpha2 = alpha2 * cos(pi/(2*N2)*(2*n2+1)*k2);
      for k1=0:N1-1
         if(k1==0)
            alpha1 = 1/sqrt(2);
         else
            alpha1 = 1;
         end
         alpha1 = alpha1 * cos(pi/(2*N1)*(2*n1+1)*k1);
         sm = sm + alpha1*alpha2*alpha3*X(k1+1,k2+1,k3+1);
      end
   end
end
IDCT3DOutput(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1) = sm;
```

In my test this is about a 50% reduction in time.
But we now sill compute `alpha1` `N3*N2` times too many, to avoid doing that we should compute all possible `alpha1` values before the loops:

```matlab
alpha1 = cos(pi/(2*N1)*(2*n1+1)*(0:N1-1));
alpha1(1) = alpha1(1) / sqrt(2);
alpha2 = cos(pi/(2*N2)*(2*n2+1)*(0:N2-1));
alpha2(1) = alpha2(1) / sqrt(2);
alpha3 = cos(pi/(2*N3)*(2*n3+1)*(0:N3-1));
alpha3(1) = alpha3(1) / sqrt(2);
sm = 0;
for k3=1:N3
   for k2=1:N2
      for k1=1:N1
         sm = sm + alpha1(k1)*alpha2(k2)*alpha3(k3)*X(k1,k2,k3);
      end
   end
end
IDCT3DOutput(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1) = sm;
```

This yields another 3.5x speed improvement. Code now also has become simpler: we can do natural loops `k1=1:N1`, and index naturally `X(k1,k2,k3)`. And it's now also much simpler to see how we can vectorize the computation. We use [MATLAB's implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) here. This requires giving the arrays `alpha1`, `alpha2` and `alpha3` the right orientation:

```matlab
alpha1 = cos(pi/(2*N1)*(2*n1+1)*(0:N1-1).'); % along 1st dimension
alpha1(1) = alpha1(1) / sqrt(2);
alpha2 = cos(pi/(2*N2)*(2*n2+1)*(0:N2-1)); % along 2nd dimension
alpha2(1) = alpha2(1) / sqrt(2);
alpha3 = cos(pi/(2*N3)*(2*n3+1)*(0:N3-1));
alpha3(1) = alpha3(1) / sqrt(2);
alpha3 = reshape(alpha3,1,1,N3); % along 3rd dimension
sm = ((X .* alpha1) .* alpha2) .* alpha3;
IDCT3DOutput(n1+1,n2+1,n3+1) = sum(sm(:));
```

This yields yet again a 3.5x speed improvement, for a total of about 14x over the original code. And yet again, the code was simplified.

When we now look at the outer loops, we again see that we can move some of these computations out of loops, which again significantly reduces the number of computations. But let's take a step back first. The DCT equation,
$$\begin{split}
x(n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}) = &\sum_{{k_1 = 0}}^{N_1 - 1} \sum_{{k_2 = 0}}^{N_2 - 1} \sum_{{k_3 = 0}}^{N_3 - 1} \epsilon_{k_{1}} \epsilon_{k_{2}} \epsilon_{k_{3}} X(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) \\
    & \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{1}} (2n_{1} + 1)k_{1}}) \\
    & \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{2}} (2n_{2} + 1)k_{2}}) \\
    & \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{3}} (2n_{3} + 1)k_{3}})
\end{split}$$
can be rewritten to separate out summations,
$$\begin{split}
x(n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}) =
& \sum_{{k_1 = 0}}^{N_1 - 1} \epsilon_{k_{1}} \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{1}} (2n_{1} + 1)k_{1}}) \Big[ \\
& \sum_{{k_2 = 0}}^{N_2 - 1} \epsilon_{k_{2}} \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{2}} (2n_{2} + 1)k_{2}}) \Big[ \\
& \sum_{{k_3 = 0}}^{N_3 - 1} \epsilon_{k_{3}} \cos({\frac {\pi}{2N_{3}} (2n_{3} + 1)k_{3}}) \Big[ X(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) \Big] \Big] \Big]
\end{split}$$
I split the lines like this and added the big brackets to illustrate that we are applying the 1D DCT three times, on each of the axes of the image. We are basically doing:

```
out = DCT1D(in, 1);
out = DCT1D(out, 2);
out = DCT1D(out, 3);
```

(with the 2nd argument the axis over which it is applied.

Let's implement this:

```matlab
function out = IDCT3D(X)
out = IDCT1D(X, 1);
out = IDCT1D(out, 2);
out = IDCT1D(out, 3);
end

function out = IDCT1D(X, dim)
N = size(X, dim);
sz = ones(1,3);
sz(dim) = N;
index = {':',':',':'};
out = zeros(size(X));
for n = 0:N-1
   alpha = cos(pi/(2*N)*(2*n+1)*(0:N-1));
   alpha(1) = alpha(1) / sqrt(2);
   alpha = reshape(alpha, sz);
   index{dim} = n + 1;
   out(index{:}) = sum(X .* alpha, dim);
end
end
```

This gives me about 80x speedup over the previous fastest implementation, about 1200x speedup over the original one. (I hope I didn't mess up anything and the result is still correct...)